# Dropdown bootstrap got separated

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I tried to make dropdown bootstrap menu and there is border at the bottom of the dropdown using `<hr>`

[image]

the problem is the dropdown menu jump the 
`<hr>`
line.

here is the html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <b>Available at :</b> 
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            List<span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        @foreach ($listings as $listing)
            <li>Text</li><br>
        @endforeach
        </ul>
    <hr>
    </div>
```

under dropdown styling, there is `top : 100%` if I untick it, the dropdown list display correctly.

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 2px 0 0;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
list-style: none;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
```

Anyone know how to fix this so the dropdown will display exactly at the bottom of Available at :List ? 
more like this

[image]

Comment: edit your question and add the html also

Comment: added the html code and question with desired output picture

Comment: Please create a JSfiddle or codepen for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with adding `<div class="col-md-12">` before the dropdown. and another `<div class="col-md-12">` for `<hr>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `top: 20px; left: 15px;` instead of `top: 100%; left: 0;` in your css. this would fix your problem.

Look here: http://www.bootply.com/qyGxdV9m0t#

Comment: this will make dropdown to always display at the top of the page, it will mess up when viewing in small display.